# vector iterator and template functions

Tags: c++, templates, vector, iterator

Can somebody explain to me why the code below works and produce true? `v1.begin()` produces an iterator but when debugging if I inspect the value of `v1.begin()` inside the compare function I see the value of the first element of the vector.

Is this related to the fact that one needs to use `typename vector<T>::iterator` it to name an iterator inside a template? It would be great if somebody could elaborate on this

Thanks

```
template<class U, class V> bool compare(const U &v1, const U &v2, const V &v3) {
    if ((v1 == v2) && (v2 == v3) ){
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}


#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    vector<int>     v1(10,3);
    vector<int>     v2(10,3);
    bool iComp = compare(v1.begin(), v1.begin() + 2, v2.begin());
    cout << typeid(v1.begin()).name() << "    "  << *v2.begin() << endl;

    return 1;
}
```

Comment: `iComp` evaluates to `false`.  So I don't understand the question!

Comment: You are right, I had not checked the value of iComp but simply the value of v1, v2 and v3 in the function. I dont know for what reason but hovering over v1, v2 and v3 in VC++ 2010 inisde the fucntion shows the value of 3 for the three variables so I asssumed that it would produce True. It is great that it doesnt as that is what logic was telling me. Sorry for not having checked this carefully.

Comment: Visual C++ helpfully displays what is *pointed to* by the iterator.  That is what you are seeing. `v1`, `v2` and `v3` are all iterators.

Comment: @Oli - that may be helpful when you are sure about the logic of a language not when you are trying to learn it ;-)

Comment: Upvoted question:  I learned a lot about C++ by playing with it under a debugger.

Answer (score 1):

`compare` returns `true` if and only if all three iterators point to the same object. If the iterators pointed to objects of different types, there could be a compilation error.

The iterators point to different objects, because the arguments are all different, so `compare` returns `false`. This result is thrown away.

Then the program prints a unique string identifying the type `std::vector< int >::iterator`. This might be a long string mentioning the fragments `std`, `vector`, and `iterator`, or it might be simply `pi` for "pointer to integer," if the `<vector>` implementation uses `typedef T *iterator`.

Finally it prints `10` because that is the first value in `v2`.